# Automatically begin speedtest using Ookla App and get the result programmatically in android

Tags: android

mmm...I have a task to get internet speed test,ping, download speed, upload speed, and etc by using Ookla on android... I already know to lunch Ookla programmatically using an intent, but the problem is when ookla is launched, I need to press "begin" test button to run internet speed...Here I just want to begin ookla internet speed test without using user interaction...So when the ookla is launched I want to begin the test automatically too... Is there any way for doing this..??? like sending something from my launcher intent..? or mmm... I don't know exactly...

Thanks in advance...:)

Note:
*sorry for stupid question may be.. :)
*I have found a project for doing this speedtest programmatically, but it needs a server. and I don't have or don't wanna use a server here.. :)

Comment: "I have a task to get internet speed test,ping, download speed, upload speed, and etc by using Ookla on android" -- then you will need to talk to Ookla, to see if they have options for this, whether what you want to do adheres to their terms of service, etc.

Comment: yeeep.. I have tried that yesterday...but It seemed that I didn't have a way for contacting them from their web.. So I though or hoped that may be someone had tried this on stackoverflow... :)

Comment: Aand... thanks so much for you commen Mr. CommonsWare... :)

Comment: @HyosokaPoipo I am aslo panning to contact speedtest.nt Ookla, Did you get the same?

Comment: Nopeee.. I didn't get anything... :)
I couldn't contact them from their customer service...

Comment: btw... please tell me too if you get anything from Ookla ehehe...